Google Sheets Data Validation List from Named Range Not Refreshing?
I have a Google Sheets document that makes use of named ranges in data validation dropdown lists.
One named range, "DevReports", is used in 3 dropdowns on a sheet.
I'm finding quite often now that when the dropdowns pointed at this named range are selected, it is listing no options, despite there being data in the location that the named range points at and the data validation options appearing to be configured correctly.

Here's the basic configuration:


Report(s) are listed by their ID numbers (separated by commas if there's more than 1) in a cell labelled "Reports(s)"
Transpose() & Split() functions separates the comma-separated report IDs in to rows and then a Vlookup() function returns the report titles from another sheet (these titles are what will be used in the data validation list)
The range containing the report titles is stored as a named range called "DevReports" for this sheet
The named range is used as a data validation list next to the "Report:" label

This is the summarised data validation for the "Report:" dropdown:

...and this is the full detail of those data validation settings:

Notice how it seems to preview the option I would be expecting to see in the dropdown list even though it then doesn't actually display it in the spreadsheet..?!
The only way I've found to get it to work again is to change the data validation to something else, e.g. to a simple "Drop-down" rather than "Drop-down (from a range)"...

...then switch it back to "Drop-down (from a range)" and point it at =DevReports and it then seems to work in the spreadsheet as expected:

The sheet that this is on is from a template that gets duplicated many times, so it's getting tedious to apply this workaround each time I need a copy of the template.
Is there anything obvious I've missed? Is there a Apps Script solution that might help nudge/refresh these data validation to named range links rather than using my current workaround?
UPDATE
The issue was happening intermittently, but I think I've pinned the specific scenario down.
The template sheet that gets copied is copied using a Apps Script procedure initiated from a button on another sheet.
If I run the copy template sheet procedure and then supply the report ID to the new copy, the dropdown list populates correctly.
If I run the copy template sheet procedure and close the spreadsheet before supplying the report ID to the new copy, when I reopen the spreadsheet later and provide the report ID, the dropdown list does not populate. Why might that be?

When does the issue happen? Upon opening the spreadsheet, after editing the Report(s) cell, etc?

@user27425627 both. Though when the sheet is intitially copied from the template sheet, I would expect the Reports(s) cell to be blank and therefore the dropdown to not have any options. It's when the Reports(s) cell is filled-in with a valid report ID and I can see the named range has values that I'm confused as to why the dropdown doesn't then populate those same values.

It's almost as if something is still pointing at the template sheet... i.e. cached or something..?

What happens if, before copying the template, you add the name of the sheet in the criteria range's formula? I.e. Criteria: \n Drop-down (from a range) \n ='TemplateSheetName'!DevReports.

Could turning "Iterative calculation" from File>Settings>Calculation of the Google sheet file help?

@user27425627 it didn't make any difference unfortunately :(

@4thAnd1 iterative calculation didn't fix it unfortunately

I've added an update as it seems to be happening in a particular scenario

Could refreshing the data validation work? Maybe you can try refreshing the data validation after specific events like opening the sheet you can take a look at this: on how you can possibly refresh the data validation
setDataValidation
